# Foreach Loop in a view doesn't work in CI3 view

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach, codeigniter-3

Hi I'm trying to do foreach loop on a view but it's not showing. I've checked the database and there's data. I've checked the QueryBuilder on the model and run the query on phpmyadmin and its working. Do you guys know what happened?

view:

```
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <section class="content">
        <div class="row">
<?php
foreach ($node as $d) {
?>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                <div class="box box-device box-solid" id="device_<?php echo $d['id_device']; ?>">
                    <div class="box-header">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                                <button aria-pressed="false" data-device="<?php echo $d['id_device']; ?>" class="btn btn-onoff btn-sm btn-toggle<?php echo ($d['status_device'] == 1) ? ' active': ''; ?>" data-toggle="button" type="button">
                                    <div class="handle"></div>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
                                <h3 class="box-title<?php echo ($d['rule'] == 0) ? ' notactive': ''; ?>"><?php echo $d['nama_device']; ?></h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-body text-center" onclick="window.location.href = '<?php echo site_url('Setting/rule/' . $d['id_device']); ?>'">
                        <img alt="<?php echo $d['nama_device']; ?>" src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/device/' . $d['foto']); ?>" />
                        <h4><?php echo $d['nama_device']; ?></h4>
                        <p><?php echo $d['id_device']; ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-footer">
                        <a class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-lg btn-detail" href="<?php echo site_url('Setting/rule/' . $d['id_device']); ?>">View Rule</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
<?php
}
?>
        </div>
    </section>
    <?php $this->load->view('components/version'); ?>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public function rulenode() {
        $this->data['sub_title'] = 'Setting - Rule';
        $this->load->model('Mrule');
        $this->data['node'] = $this->Mrule->device();
        $this->load->view('setting/rulenode', $this->data);
    }
```

Model:

```
public function device() {
        $this->db->select('id_device, nama_device, foto, status_device');
        $this->db->from('tb_device');
        $this->db->join('arduino_rule', 'id_device = id_node');
        return $this->db->get()->result_array();

        // var_dump($this->db->last_query());
    }
```

Comment: in your view: before the foreach() loop, check what `print_r($node);` shows. You need to check it most likely in your browser's inspector (press F12)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
 $node = $this->db->get('table_name');  
 foreach ($node as $d) {
?>
```